# using regex for htaccess 301 redirects

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a trouble with writing regex for 301 redirects in hataccess.
I want to change this url:

```
https://sample.com/234234-tonino-lamborghini/2621-tonino-lamborghini-ttr001004--ita.html
```

with this one:

```
https://sample.com/tonino-lamborghini/tonino-lamborghini-ttr001004-ita
```

it will remove any numbers starts with "/" and end by "-" also makes "--" to "-" anywhere and finally remove ".html" from end of url.

Comment: How are you trying to executing the Regex exactly? Are you processing the URL's inside a script for example or maybe inside a terminal?

Comment: No, I have a website migrate and have ugly urls that want to prety them.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this expression inside your .htaccess configuratuion file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/[0-9]+-[^/]+/(.+?)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Note that this regular expression will only work in an Apache .htaccess file.**

Comment: regex seems be ok but I have no success to use in htaccess

Comment: It could be that it needs to have a direct beginning and ending so you could try  this: `^(https://sample\.com/)\d+-([\w-]+/)\d+-([\w-]+)-(\w+)\.html$`

Comment: RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule (https:\/\/sample\.com\/)\d+-([\w-]+\/)\d+-([\w-]+)-(\w+)\.html $1$2$3$4 [R=301,L]
this must be ok but i don't know why don't act.

Comment: also the "--" may be repeated other places not only before end

Comment: I've made a change in my answer please give it another look

Comment: your code much helped but I have to make some changes to work with my basic url in the question:
RewriteRule ^(.*)--(.*)$ $1-$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule [0-9]+-([^\/]+\/)[0-9]+-(.+?)\.html$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
It works completely in two steps.

Comment: Ah okay, at least your problem is solved :)

Comment: Could you accept the answer if it fulfills your needs so other people would find it more easily?

Comment: ok, sure, pls update your answer with above code and mention that this may be done with two step redirection when url redirection is some complicated, Although two step redirection may not look professional.